# codeigniter browser windows problem?

Tags: codeigniter

Im having a problem in codeignter where I will have two browser windows open (a & b) for the same application, and when I click a link or similar in browser a, the application goes to the correct link, but browser b becomes active instead?

This is really frustrating, and I need to get to the bottom of why this is happening...

Im not sure if that explains it properly, but im sure this is a simple fix but I cant find any information on it...?

Anyone have any ideas on what may be causing this?

Also, this is happening in FF, Chrome & Safari (Have not tested in IE)

Comment: If you want any help, you'll probably need to post the code that it took to get to this point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this is application-wide and there is no specific code that I could post that is related to this... If I could figure out where the problem is coming from, eg cookies etc, I may be able to start hunting down the source of the problem... but at the moment, I dont know where to start so need a bit of a heads-up...

Comment: What do you mean by "browser b becomes active instead"?

Comment: ok, so say I have browser A full screen as thats the browser I want to work with, and I have browser B minimised (or on another screen etc)... when I click anything on browser A (within the application, links etc) Browser B will popup (maximise) or become into focus, and become the active browser window... leaving Browser A inactive and out of focus... if I had browser B behind browser A, it would come in front... I hope that makes sense, its hard to explain... Any help in resolving this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so for anyone else that comes across this problem, it was a javascript file for a color picker that was causing the problem... all fixed now, knew it would be something simple lol

Thanks!